# Windows 10 and a hidden Linux on the same machine

Tags: windows-10

How could I tell if Linux has been being used on my Windows 10 machine? Or is there a CMD command that will truly show all files or programs even if they are hidden?

Comment: Did you buy this machine used and you just want to know it's history? You really must be more specific about your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Linux could be run in a Windows PC in one of four ways:

1. in a virtual machine;
2. by something like WUBI, which installs Ubuntu in a Windows file system;
3. in a separate partition; or
4. by booting a configured system from an external disc.

You can use `dir /a` to show all files, including hidden and system files, or `dir /a:h` to show hidden only. You can add other parameters, such as `/s` to search subdirectories.

Alternatively, you can use `attrib` without a `+` or `-` parameter to list files with their attributes (this also can take `/s`).

Both of these commands will find the files associated with the first two cases. However, in the third case a native Linux file system will not mountable in Windows without installing other software. To see this you will need to use the `list volume` command in `diskpart`, but it may not be obvious if the Linux volume has not been labelled informatively.

In the fourth case, all the files are on the external disc, and unless changes were made there will be nothing to show that Linux was ever run.